# Can I use an int (as opposed to a char) array as a memory arena where objects are created with placement new?

Tags: c++, object, object-lifetime, placement-new

The question concerns a home-grown container template (a kind of std::array/vector hybrid) which holds an untyped array for storage. New elements are added by a push_back() member function which copy-constructs an element via placement new. This way the container does not require the contained type to have a default constructor, and we avoid default-constructing potentially never needed elements.

Typically, such storage would be a character type like std::byte.

We are using a bouquet of compilers. One of them predates the C++11 alignment facilities like `alignas`or `aligned_storage`. Absent that, they all all need different pragmas or attributes to guarantee alignment. In order to simplify the build and avoid manual alignment computation noise, we had the idea to use an array of 32 bit integers which have an alignment guarantee. Here is the core of the implementation:

```
template <class T> struct vec
{
  uint32_t storage[NUM];
  T *freeMem;
  vec() : freeMem((T *)storage) {}
  T *push_back(const T &t) {  return new (freeMem++) T(t); }
};
```

Notably, we use a typed (differently typed than the storage array) pointer to pass the storage location to placement new; we think that's not an aliasing violation because we don't read or write through it before the object with type T is created.

Also notable is that the newly created objects may incompletely straddle two or more of the original int objects in the storage area, if sizeof(T) is not a multiple of sizeof(uint32_t).

I would think we have neither aliasing nor object lifetime issues. Is that so?

Comment: The correct way to avoid alignment issues is to use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead, eg: `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type storage[NUM];`  or in C++14 and later: `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage[NUM];`

Comment: @RemyLebeau How much I'd love to do that; but one of the compilers is from 1998.

Comment: So, what is stopping you from writing your own version of `aligned_storage` for older compilers? it is just a simple struct with 1 data member, `type`, that is a byte array of the correct size to hold the total size and alignment padding of a single `T`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The example implementation on cppreference uses the alignas specification which is not available on one of our compilers. Absent some compiler specific attribute/pragma which we try to avoid there is no way to truly align objects or data members which don't "naturally" require alignment, is there?

Comment: You can calculate the alignment by creating an array of 2 `T`s and seeing how many bytes are allocated for the 1st element.  Or maybe just an array of 1 `T` and looking at the size of the whole array.

Comment: Using a `uint32_t` does not guarantee alignment and alignment might not be enough for larger type like a double. If you want to be sure that your code works as expected, you have to control or validate any assumption you make. In 1998, no alignment or alignment to even address (2 bytes) was common. It make little sense to write code that works on both pre-2011 and modern compilers as so many things have changed since then.

Comment: @Phil1970 I won't argue with you that it would be desirable to replace that old compiler but it is validated and the process is hard and costly. Re "so many things have changed since then": True, but almost all of them preserved backwards compatibility. That's probably one thing that hobbles C++'s  development  from the moment of its conception -- and it's amazing what *can* be done within those constraints.

Comment: @PasserBy Your deleted post looks reasonable, why did you delete it?